# Horror movie which takes place in an old house with a girl with powers.

Tags: horror, story-identification, movie

So, I saw this movie, like 4 (or more) years ago. The action took place in an old house. The main character is a girl (around 25 years old) who has the power to see the dead people, demons and so on. She inherited this power from her mother or grandmother (I can't remember). There are a lot of jump scares in that movie. I remember there were a lot of dead people in that house, especially in the basement, and most of them weren't evil, but they were controlled by a very powerful demon, I think.

I remember a scene in which the girl fell through a floor in the basement and a lot of dead people jumped on her, covering the girl, and her mother or grandmother always said to "Let them in" and she did in that moment and all of them disappeared.

I really want to see this movie again, please help me. :)

Answer (score 3):

**[The Haunting in Connecticut 2: Ghosts of Georgia](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1457765/)**, which indeed came out 4 years prior (2013). From [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_haunting_in_connecticut_2_ghosts_of_georgia):

> Building on the terror of *A Haunting in Connecticut*, this horrifying tale traces a young family's nightmarish descent into a centuries-old Southern hell. When Andy Wyrick (Chad Michael Murray, House of Wax) moves his wife Lisa (Abigail Spencer, TV's "Mad Men") and daughter Heidi to an historic home in Georgia, they quickly discover they are not the house's only inhabitants. Joined by Lisa's free-spirited sister, Joyce (Katee Sackhoff, TV's "Battlestar Galactica"), the family soon comes face-to-face with a bone-chilling mystery born of a deranged desire...a haunting secret rising from underground and threatening to bring down anyone in its path.

Heidi and Lisa have visions and it runs in the family (the aunt and grandmother had them too). Lisa eventually discovers that the ghosts haunting them were really the victims of an Underground Railroad stationmaster, and is able to conquer them all in the basement **when she sees a vision of her mom telling her to "let them in" and embrace her visions.**

Here's the trailer: